# Why first one treat it as boolean value and second not?

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button, onchange

I want to toggle the state of two div's based on the radio button. Based on the value I want to toggle div's visibility. First div showing and hiding based on `this.value` but second case I'm using `!this.value` it's not working , also I've tried `!Boolean(this.value)`.

```js
$('[name="radio"]').change(function() {
  console.log(this.value,!this.value);
  $('#first').toggle(this.value); // this works
  $('#second').toggle(!this.value); // this one not
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="radio" value="false" />
<input type="radio" name="radio" value="true" />

<div id="first">1</div>
<div id="second">2</div>
```

> Why first one treat it as **Boolean** value and second not?

Comment: `!this.value` will always be evaluated as `false`

Comment: @RayonDabre :  ok that's fine, what about first case?

Comment: Answer for second question is got...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `this.value` is a string either `'true'` or `'false'` both are truthy values so negating it will always give `false`. That is your second condition will never be true

```js
$('[name="radio"]').change(function() {
  console.log(this.value, !this.value);
  var value = this.value === 'true';
  $('#first').toggle(value);
  $('#second').toggle(!value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="radio" value="false" />
<input type="radio" name="radio" value="true" />

<div id="first">1</div>
<div id="second">2</div>
```

Also have a look at the `toggle()` method

```
toggle: function( state ) {
    if ( typeof state === "boolean" ) {
        return state ? this.show() : this.hide();
    }

    return this.each(function() {
        if ( isHidden( this ) ) {
            jQuery( this ).show();
        } else {
            jQuery( this ).hide();
        }
    });
}
```

As you can see, of the `value` is not of type `boolean` then it is not considered, since for the `first` one you are passing a string it is always toggled

Comment: `Why first one treat it as boolean value and second not?`

Comment: @ArunPJohny, Will it invert the existing state all the time(for first case) ?

Comment: @RayonDabre yes, that is the default nature of toggle if no parameter is passed

Comment: @ArunPJohny :  oops now I got the answer.... there is no use of that parameter..... I need to do `toggle(this.value=='true')` instead

Comment: @ArunPJohny, You can add this if you like: http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.11.2&fn=jQuery.fn.toggle

Comment: @PranavCBalan Instead of struggling with `value`, you can use `this.checked` https://jsfiddle.net/dmejs0p0/1/

Comment: @PranavCBalan https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535838(v=vs.85).aspx#properties I hope you can get some valid info from there.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy :  let me check that :)

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy : got it..... for that I need to get first or second radio and need to get it's checked property....